# QuickSort for vector<string>

Tags: c++

I'm new to recursion and get kind of confused by it this is my first time coding Quick Sort for a string I keep getting an error. Does anyone know where I messed up?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void SwapValue(string &a, string &b) 
{
   string t = a;
   a = b;
   b = t;
}

void quicksort(vector<string> &list, int first, int end)
{
  int l = first;
  int r = end;
  int pivot = ((first + end) / 2);
  while (l <= r)
  {
    while (list[l] <= (list[pivot]))
      ++l;
    while (list[r] >= (list[pivot]))
      --r;
    if (l <= r)
    {
      swap(list[l], list[r]);
      ++l;
      --r;
    }
  }
  if (first <= r)
    quicksort(list, first, r);
  if (end >= l)
    quicksort(list, l, end);
}

void print(vector <string> const &a)
{
   cout << "[ ";

   for(int i=0; i < a.size(); i++)
   {
     cout << a[i] << ' ';
   }
   cout << ']';
}

int main()
{
  vector<string> test = {"Bob", "Andrew", "Joe"};
  quicksort(test, 0, test.size()-1);
  print(test);
  return 0;
}
```

I thought about getting the ASCII values of the first char within the string but I would have to use a nested forloop to retrieve the character and wouldn't that make QuickSort slower?

Comment: What error do you keep getting?

Comment: @273K I get no errors it just becomes an infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement:

```
while (list[l] <= (pivot))
```

How does that even compile?  Comparing a string to an integer?

I suspect you mean:

```
while (list[l] <= list[pivot])
```

Similar treatment is also needed for the `while (list[r] >= (pivot))` statement. And I don't think you want to use `>=` on the right side.

```
while (i <= r)
```

That won't compile either since `i` is not defined.  I suspect you meant `l`, not 'i'.

Comment: I updated it but now its stuck at an infinite loop. I ran it with the debugger seems like.   if (end >= l) is the issue.